# Cloudflare SSL, but the connection shows as insecure

Tags: wordpress, ssl, encryption, https, cloudflare

I followed a tutorial to get free SSL for my website. I've done it two times already - without any issues. However this time the connection shows as insecure in firefox.

> This Website is not safe, because it contains unencrypted elements (eg. graphics) or the encryption isn't strong enough.

(My browser is in German so this is probably not exactly what an English browser would tell you)

Tutorial can be found here: 
http://www.blackhatworld.com/blackhat-seo/white-hat-seo/756144-how-free-ssl-wordpress-website-2.html

This is the website:

```
https://instasound.net/
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: https://www.whynopadlock.com/  Valid Certificate found.
 Certificate valid through: Sep 30 23:59:59 2016 GMT
Certificate Issuer: COMODO CA Limited
SSL Protocols Supported: TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the website with Pingdom http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/
and found out that some images where somehow transferred via http.

I simply changed the image source in the code from http to https and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The website you mentioned, https://instasound.net/  is not showing any mixed content warnings at this time. Did you already fix whatever the issue was?

Comment: Yes, I posted the solution below.